# VBA Runtime Error - 1004 Application-defined or Object-defined error

Tags: excel

Below is the code for my macro, I am attempting to combine the data of multiple sheets into one. The macro works as intended but I am receiving a debug error on this line of code.

Sheets(i).UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Sheets(i).UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, Sheets(i).UsedRange.Columns.Count).Copy NewSht.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1)

```
'Declaring the Variables
Dim LastRow, ShtCnt As Integer
Dim ShtName As String
Dim NewSht As Worksheet

'Assinging a Sheet Name by UserInput
ShtName:
ShtName = InputBox("Enter the Sheet Name you want to create", "Merge Sheet", "Master Sheet")

'Count of Total Worksheet in the present workbook
ShtCnt = Sheets.Count

'Using For Loop check if the worksheet exists
For i = 1 To ShtCnt
If Sheets(i).Name = ShtName Then
MsgBox "Sheet already Exists", , "Merge Sheet"
GoTo ShtName
End If
Next i

'Create a New Sheet
Worksheets.Add.Name = ShtName

'Assigning NewSht as Current Sheet
Set NewSht = ActiveSheet

'Moving Worksheet to the beginning of this workbook
NewSht.Move before:=Worksheets(1)

'Copying all the data to the New Sheet Using For Loop
For i = 2 To ShtCnt + 1

'If i=2 Then copy all the data from the second sheet including header.
If i = 2 Then
Sheets(i).UsedRange.Copy NewSht.Cells(1, 1)
Else

'If i is greater than 2 then copy all the data excluding Header(1st Row).
Sheets(i).UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Sheets(i).UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, Sheets(i).UsedRange.Columns.Count).Copy NewSht.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1)
End If
LastRow = NewSht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Next i

'Displaying the Message after copying data successfully
MsgBox "Data has been copied to " & ShtName, , "Merge Sheet"

End Sub
```

Comment: I just tested your code with 3 simple sheets in 64bit Excel from Office 365 on Windows 10, and it worked fine, other than I had to add "Sub Test()" as a first line, but I assume that was just an oversight when you posted your code.  A 1004 error is typically when you try to access an unset or null object.  Perhaps there is something about your dataset, hidden sheets, or something causing it.  To find a null object, split that line into several and put break points. Dim s,u,o,r as variant : set s = Sheet(i) : set u = s.UsedRange : set o = u.Offset(1, 0) : set r = u.Rows : o.Resize(...)